# Where to put a library shared between portlets in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, portlet

I need to share a library (built in-house) between portlets and I prefer to put it in a common place instead of adding it as dependency to every portlet that need it because I want to update the library once. Can I build a hook or ext plugin that the portlets can refer to and access the library? I know that you can add it to the common library directory and add it to `liferay-plugin-package.properties` for each portlet but the location depends on the application server. I want to know, there is a standard or cleaner way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the tomcat bundle, the common usage is to put these in the `tomcat/lib/ext` folder.

There is one big drawback, every modification in this folder will require a server restart.

Comment: With this method the libraries will load with shared classloader, also you must take attention with a static attributes.

Comment: Note that it is also possible to have multiple portlets in a single WAR. So if, for some reason, you do not want to add stuff to global libs, you can include all your portlets in a single WAR-file. This way you always have the necessary dependencies available, no matter what Liferay installation is running.